# How to fix CardView sticks to left side?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My CardView sticks to the left side of RecyclerView like this:

[image]

I'm using adapter for recycler view:

**RecyclerView**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:title="HTML" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**item view**

```
<androidx.widget.CardView
  andorid:layout_height="150dp"
  andorid:layout_width="150dp"
  android:margin="4dp">
    <TextView
     andorid:layout_height="wrap_content"
     andorid:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but your question is unclear. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: In my screenshot, you see, there are card view sticked to the left side. And look ugly. I need to align cardviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try this and if not work try next solution
set this line to your recyclerView in XML

```
  android:gravity="center"
```

if not work change your itemView like this :

```
 <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="158dp"
   android:layout_height="158dp">


   <androidx.widget.CardView
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     andorid:layout_height="150dp"
     andorid:layout_width="150dp"
     >

     <TextView
        andorid:layout_height="wrap_content"
        andorid:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </androidx.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make the recycleview like a gridview that create two columns

With androidX libraries simply do:

In xml

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
   app:spanCount="2"/>
```

If progmatically

```
  RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

And also try adjust the margin of the cardview

Answer (score 0):

are you set viewgroup variable in your view inflater like this

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: of course, i think my problem in XML layouts. something wrong with align